# Question about git rm --cached, reset, and push

Tags: git, git-push

Currently, I have, on local branch master, a folder structure like:

```
project
    models
    web
        app
        app_env (vritualenv)
        requirements.txt
```

I want to push everything besides models and app_env code to app_demo, a remote branch under origin.

I did cd to project and did:

```
git add .
git rm --cached -r models
git rm --cached -r web/app_env
git commit -m "Please work"
git push origin master:web_demo
```

But got

```
remote: error: File models/variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001 is 986.28 MB; 
this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

! [remote rejected]   master -> app_demo (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Because some file under models was too big. I thought I removed it already!? Why is this happening?

Comment: The large file is part of your branch's history, so `rm --cached` is not enough.  You need to remove all traces of this file from your history.  See filter branch or rebase for possible options.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `git add .` You should add individual files or directories like

```
git add web/app
```

If you do a `git status` , you'll get all the files which are unstaged, then you can select individual files and add them one by one.